# Html tag in json object

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have started on a new project. It is the first time that I see the following webservice output. This following json object text contains html tags.

I wonder how do you parse it to string or how do you know where the paragraph starts? or do you think that I should contact web service developer guy to fix this?

[image]

Comment: it seems like that is contend intended for display, hence the included markup, no? Can you say in more detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It is news application and I want to display this text to app user along with the image.

Comment: ok if this format is not usable for your purpose then you should build a regular expression that matches the bits in between the <p> tags. Or wait for someone more knowledgeable about ios development to chime in ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
```

To turn the data into dictionary. Then you can access the value of "icerik" by traversing the dictionary tree with NSArray/NSDictionary. For your case example,
first nest is a dictionary of key "news" with array objects. So you get the the array out of it:

```
NSArray *newsArray = [JSON objectForKey:@"news"];
```

Then you get the first news item by getting another dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *firstNews = [newsArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then you can get icerik:

```
NSString *icerik = [firstNews objectForKey:@"icerik"];
```

Once you get the value as string, you need to do some string manipulation on it (many ways to do this)

Answer (score 1):

You can get your html string as

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

NSString *icerik = json[@"news"][0][@"icerik"];
```

You can use UIWebView or UITextView to load html string.

```
NSString *myHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body>%@</body></html>" ,icerik ];
[yourWebView loadHTMLString:myHTML baseURL:nil];
```